# Resizing background of scene2d table to match size of the table

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have Table made with scene2d and I attempt to add some background - image defined in table's skin. Is it possible for scene2d to automaticly resize image to match the size of table? My image is quite a bit larger than table and if I add background by `debugTable.setBackground("window");` it appears much larger than table (original size of the image). I've tried to set min sizes on background to 0 but it did't help.

One solution would be to not to use background property of table but to add new actor that handles drawing of background, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do this using only default scene2d interface.

Code to create table:

```
debugTable = new Table(skin);
debugTable.setBackground("window");

fpsLabel = new Label("", skin);
possLabel = new Label("", skin);

debugTable.add(new Label("FPS", skin));
debugTable.add(fpsLabel);
debugTable.row();
debugTable.add(new Label("poss", skin));
debugTable.add(possLabel);
debugTable.pack();
stage.addActor(debugTable);
```

Table extends to original size of background texture:
[image]

Table without background:
[image]

Also I'm using ScreenViewport for stage

Comment: This is a line from `Table.drawBackground()` method: `background.draw(batch, x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());` Where `getWidth()` and getHeight() return exactly the size of the `Table`. So I can't think of a case, where it draws the background bigger than the table. Try running with `table.debug()` to visualize table's size, cells, etc to see exactly what's happening. Also, a screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Did you override any of `Table` methods related to drawing? Is your background drawable a `NinepatchDrawable`?

Comment: Added screenshots and code, sorry for initial quality of question I was half asleep.

Comment: I think it's because of your `window` ninepatch asset pads (i.e. non-strechable borders). You don't explicitly specify the `debugTable` size, right? So when calling `debugTable.pack()` it automatically fits the labels in the ninepatch stretchable area. So, try changing the `window` ninepatch pads. They are probably too big.

Comment: Sorry, as you tried, you still need to set background drawable min size to 0, or some minimum possible value for the ninepatch. Call `setMinWidth(0)` and `setMinHeight(0)` on 'window' drawable.

Comment: How are you setting min size 0 on the drawable? That should do it.